# Interval code with transform option added using Jquery is working only one time

Tags: jquery, css

I have trouble with following code:

```
var permission = 0;

setInterval(function() {size()}, 5000);

function size(){

if (permission == true){

    if (turn == 0){

        $(document).ready(function(){


            $('img#me').css('transform', 'rotateX(360deg)');

            turn = 1;

        });

    }
    else{

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('img#contact').css('transform', 'rotateY(360deg)');

            turn = 0;

        });

    }
}
```

}

The rotations are working only one time for each element.
After one rotation next should do in about 5 seconds but it isn't.
I have looked for suggestions in the internet but haven't found anything helpful.

Thanks for help.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I'm trying to do an CSS transform animation ran every 5 seconds in opposite img but it runs only one time for each img and later it's doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second time that you set the transform, there is no change so nothing will happen. Keep increasing the angle for each time that you set the transform:

```js
var permission = true;
var turn = 0;
var angle1 = 0;
var angle2 = 0;

setInterval(function() {size()}, 2000);

function size(){
  if (permission == true){
    if (turn == 0){
      $(document).ready(function(){
        angle1 += 360;
        $('img#me').css('transform', 'rotateX(' + angle1 + 'deg)');
        turn = 1;
      });
    } else {
      $(document).ready(function(){
        angle2 += 360;
        $('img#contact').css('transform', 'rotateY(' + angle2 + 'deg)');
        turn = 0;
      });
    }
  }

}
```

```css
img { transition-duration: 1s; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://placekitten.com/125/130" id="me">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/125/130" id="contact">
```

Answer (score 1):

Several errors here:

- `$.ready()` should not be called several times move it arrounf the `setInterval`;
- Once you set the css transform you need to remove the second element transform element.

Here is an example: [**JSnippet Demo**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/333/Animate-one-by-one-with-setInterval)

jQuery:

```
var permission = true;
var turn = true;
$(function(){
  setInterval(function() {size()}, 2500);
});

function size(){
  if (permission){
    if (turn){
        $('img#me').addClass('animate').css('transform', 'rotateX(360deg)');
        $('img#contact').removeClass('animate').css('transform', '');
        turn = false;
    } else {
        $('img#contact').addClass('animate').css('transform', 'rotateY(360deg)');
        $('img#me').removeClass('animate').css('transform', '');
        turn = true;
    }
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
img.animate {
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

Comment: It's actally perfectly fine to call `$.ready` any time you like. If the event hasn't happened yet the function will be bound as an event handler for it, otherwise the function will be called directly. Using it inside the interval callback means that the interval can be started before the ready event.